# Pullout single side handle kitchen faucet intermittent

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, faucet, pull

Less than a year old, no name on faucet or instructions. The feeling of turning on seems smooth and no different when it fails or works. Seems to be getting worse over the past week. If left on it drips, but won't come on without turning it back off and on a time or three.

If it's relevant, there's a handsfree box, but we have it set on manual and haven't used the handsfree the whole time it's been in.

Appreciate any suggestions before I take it out and replace it.

Comment: Can't promise anything but a few pictures of the faucet would sure help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: it's possible that, even on the manual setting  the handsfree box requires batteries